# Python 3: Verifying port number (integer between 1-65535)

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to verify if a given port number is valid or not.

**1st Attempt**

```
PortNumber = input("Enter a port number: ")
if PortNumber.isdigit() == True:
   print("This is a VALID port number.")
else:
   print("This is NOT a valid port number.")
```

**Output**

```
C:\> python test.py
Enter a port number: a
This is NOT a valid port number.

C:\> python test.py
Enter a port number: -1
This is NOT a valid port number.

C:\> python test.py
Enter a port number: 8
This is a VALID port number.

C:\> python test.py
Enter a port number: 88888
This is a VALID port number.

C:\>
```

The only problem with this code is the port number has to be an integer between `1-65535`.

**2nd attempt**

```
PortNumber = int(input("Enter a port number: "))
if 1<= PortNumber <= 65535:
    print('This is a VALID port number.')
else:
    print('This is NOT a valid port number.')
```

**Output**

```
C:\> python test2.py
Enter a port number: 65535
This is a VALID port number.

C:\> python test2.py
Enter a port number: 65536
This is NOT a valid port number.

C:\> python test2.py
Enter a port number: -1
This is NOT a valid port number.

C:\> python test2.py
Enter a port number: a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    PortNumber = int(input("Enter a port number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

C:\>
```

I managed to filter out the numbers between `1-65535` in second code, however there is another problem with the `a` character.

How can I combine both ideas in the code?

Comment: What is your question? Why you cannot convert the string `'a'` to an integer?

Comment: Try to use the `try except` block to filter out the `ValueError` (case with *a*)

Comment: Port 0 is legal too.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
try:
    port = int(input("Enter a port number: "))
    if 1 <= port <= 65535:
        print("This is a VALID port number.")
    else:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print("This is NOT a VALID port number.")
```

Comment: This is the appropriate way to approach this.  Entering invalid value is an exceptional circumstance, and catching the `ValueError` is the appropriate course of action.

Comment: This works for **Python 3**.  In Python 2, inputting a non-numeric for `port` raises a `NameError` which is not caught.  I'm unsure the appropriate way to catch this for Python 2 except to catch the NameError as well:  `except (ValueError, NameError):`

Comment: Also to note:  the behaviour is different between Python 2 and 3.  In 2, a numeric float `port` is silently cast to an `int`.  Python 3 raises a `ValueError` for a floating-point `port`.

Answer (score 2):

Building further I would probably separate the conditions for readability:

```
PortNumber = input("Enter a port number: ")

cond1 = PortNumber.isdigit()                # True/False
cond2 = (1 <= int(PortNumber) <= 65535)     # True/False

if cond1 and cond2:
   print("This is a VALID port number.")
else:
   print("This is NOT a valid port number.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It looks better, however there is a problem if I put char `a` in the output

`C:\> python test.py
Enter a port number: a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    cond2 = (1 <= int(PortNumber) <= 65535)     C:\> True/False
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

C:\>`

Comment: @Sabrina You are right. And this is because both are evaluated if not put in one line (Where left is first and right second).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your two approaches like:

```
PortNumber = input("Enter a port number: ")
if PortNumber.isdigit() and 1 <= int(PortNumber) <= 65535:
   print("This is a VALID port number.")
else:
   print("This is NOT a valid port number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        PortNumber = int(input("Enter a port number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: expect an integer. Try again.")
        continue
    else:
        break
if 1 <= PortNumber <= 65535:
    print('This is a VALID port number.')
else:
    print('This is NOT a valid port number.')
```

The `while` loop won't let the user any further until an integer is entered. Also, there's no need to go for `is_digit()` in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

your solution does not check for conditions such as what if a `float` or some other datatype is entered

```
PortNumber = input("Enter a port number: \n")

if not(type(PortNumber) == int): 
    print("This is NOT a valid port number.")
elif 1<= PortNumber <= 65535:
    print('This is a VALID port number.')
else:
    print("This is NOT a valid port number.")
```

Comment: 1 is not valid port number?

`# python test.py
Enter a port number:
1
This is NOT a valid port number.

#`

Comment: That's strange. works fine for me. can you try again?